# Is there a way to increase the resolution of the viewport trackball?

Tags: 3d-view

I use Turntable mode for orbiting in the viewport. I often find the sensitivity insufficient for my needs. It has a sort of baseline granularity to it that makes it hard to align edges or vertices in the view perfectly. Maybe it's constrained to 1-degree increments?

You can observe this as follows: Place a couple of edges at non-cardinal angles, establish a pivot point, zoom in quite a bit, and try to adjust the trackball such that two vertices occupy the same point in the view. I'll elaborate if needed.

I'm wondering if there's some way to increase the trackball resolution (preferably a continuous, smooth orbit). I couldn't find anything in User Preferences. I'd consider using a maintained addon.

Comment: Im not super sure if I understood, but make sure you have rotate around selection enabled, and try using the zoom to object with the . (dot) key in your num pad, that'll adjust the zoom levels to the objects scale, or vertex, works in edit mode too.

Comment: I'm not having trouble finding a pivot point. When I pivot, the trackball moves in small increments, not a continuous smooth arc. I.E.: the trackball angle changes by a 1-degree increment (or something), when I really need like a 0.1 degree change.

Comment: ahhh I understand now, I had to put up with trackball mode in Mari and absolutely hated it haha.

I tried a few keys to see if there is a "precision" mode but no luck, thing is you are rotating very few fractions of a degree around your pivot, but the zoom is exaggerating the movement, also using perspective view helps, A LOT.